# How to download ubuntu iso for dell laptop

Tags: dell, iso

I bought `dell vostro M5460(corei3 2.5GHZ)`. Ubuntu was not pre-installed in this machine. How can i download the preloaded ubuntu 12.04 iso(special build for dell)?? I googled it but didn't find any useful link.

Comment: Can you tell us more about this special ISO? What's different about it? What do you mean by "preloaded"? Disk images that are written directly to a disk to produce a "preloaded" machine are not generally ISO images.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201211-12072/  pre-installed actually. Low configuration version of dell ship with ubuntu and other will windows 8. In official ubuntu site, iso is missing.

Comment: I think this link is better (generically applicable to different Dell model):

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/models/?category=Desktop&category=Laptop&vendors=Dell

Answer (score 1):

You can find the latest dell image [here](http://linux.dell.com/files/ubuntu/precise/12.04-OSP1/).